# Use hls.js to view an encrypted stream using a binary as the key

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I'm trying to find a secure way to view an encrypted stream using `hls.js`.

One way I thought of was to have the stream playlist without the `EXT-X-KEY` tag and append it on load and then feeding the resulting blob as a URL to the `hls.js` initialiser. But I got concerns from other dev that this way the blob is going to be cached and could be extracted along with the key.

Is there a way to securely provide the `hls.js` with the key as binary and avoid caching?

Answer (score 1):

Encryption makes the HLS package unreadable if you don't have the key.

Digital Rights Management (DRM) is responsible for the secure key exchange and the licensing.

Your browser handles the secure key exchange inside the Content Decryption Module.

So what you need is a DRM system. It looks like hls.js only supports Widevine.
This looks like a good summary Widevine DRM: https://www.vdocipher.com/blog/widevine-drm-hollywood-video/